# React graph component doesn't re-render on url change present in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, axios

I'm making an interactive graph which re-renders when you select a different date. It used to re-render fine before I made some fundamental changes (moved `state` responsibilites to the components instead of `app.js`. When I change the date, it does seem to actually change the url in the component responsible for making the api call. However, it's not re-rendering even though it's in a useEffect, and it did re-render before.

I'm new to React so it might be something very obvious. I'm also not sure if this is the right way to do things so I'm open for any pointers to improve my application or best practices.

App.js: Preferably I'd remove the `useGetData` and `useURLSwitcher` in the `app.js`, but without them it's not able to load the url on start up.

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "./components/button/Button";
import useGetData from "./apiData/useGetData";
import BarChart from "./components/BarChart";
import { SpinnerDiamond } from "spinners-react";
import GraphChart from "./components/GraphChart";
import { DatePicker } from "./components/datePicker/DatePicker";
import useURLSwitcher from "./apiData/useURLSwitcher";
import { DatePickerWithButton } from "./components/datePickerWithButton/DatePickerWithButton";

const App = () => {
  
    const {url}  = useURLSwitcher()
    const { dataNew, isLoading, error } = useGetData(url);
    console.log(url)

  return isLoading ? (
    <div className="spinner">
      <SpinnerDiamond
        size={400}
        speed={100}
        secondaryColor="#354A54"
        color={"#00BAEC"}
      />
    </div>
  ) : error ? (
    console.log(error)
  ) : (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="example">
        <div className="graph-box">
          <div id="wrapper">
            <GraphChart graphData={dataNew} />
          </div>
          <div className="side-bar">
            <DatePicker
              nameOne={"Start Date"}
              nameTwo={"End Date"}
            />
            <Button name={"Apply"}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="graph-box">
          <div id="wrapper">
            <BarChart graphData={dataNew} />
          </div>
          <div className="side-bar">
            <DatePickerWithButton
              nameOne={"Start Date"}
              nameTwo={"End Date"}
              name={"Apply"}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
```

DatePickerWithButton: These used to be two separate components which I combined to make it easier to set the start,- and end dates.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./DatePickerWithButton.css";
import useURLSwitcher from "../../apiData/useURLSwitcher";
import useGetData from "../../apiData/useGetData";
import { format, parseISO } from "date-fns";

export const DatePickerWithButton = ({
  nameOne,
  nameTwo,
  name,
}) => {

    let tempStartDate ="";
    let tempEndDate= "";
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState();
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState();

    const {url} = useURLSwitcher(startDate, endDate) 
    

    const onClick = () => {
        setStartDate(tempStartDate);
        setEndDate(tempEndDate);
    }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="date-box">
        <label className="styleDate">{nameOne}</label>
        <input
          className="datePicker"
          type="date"
          onChange={(e) => tempStartDate = e.target.value}
        ></input>
      </div>
      <div className="date-box">
        <label className="styleDate">{nameTwo}</label>
        <input
          className="datePicker"
          type="date"
          onChange={(e) => tempEndDate= e.target.value}
        ></input>
      </div>
      <button className="button-28" onClick={()=> onClick()}>
        {name}
      </button>
      {console.log("start date " + startDate, " end date "+ endDate)}
    </>
  );
};
```

The custom hook I made to fetch the data:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const config = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Accept: "application/json",
};

const useGetData = (url) => {
  const [dataNew, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  useEffect(async () => {
    const { data } = await axios({
      url: url,
      method: "GET",
      data: null,
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: config,
    }).catch((err) => setError(err));
console.log(url)
    const newData = data.value.map((d) => {
      const personId = d._personId;
      const startDate =
        d._startDate;
      const endDate =
        d._endDate;

      return {
        personId,
        startDate,
        endDate,
      };
    });
    setData(newData);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, [url]);

  return {
    dataNew,
    isLoading,
    error,
  };
};

export default useGetData;
```

The second custom hook that should set the right url once selected with the `DatePickerWithButton`. Links have been pruned:

```
import { format, parseISO } from "date-fns";
import { isEmpty } from "lodash";
import useGetData from "./useGetData";

const useURLSwitcher = (setStartDate, setEndDate) => {
  const startDate = setStartDate;
  const endDate = setEndDate;
  console.log(setStartDate);
  console.log(setEndDate);
  let url = "";
  const RawThisYear = new Date();
  const RawLastYear = new Date();
  RawLastYear.setFullYear(RawLastYear.getFullYear() - 5);
  const ThisYear = format(RawThisYear, "yyyy-dd-MM");
  const LastYear = format(RawLastYear, "yyyy-dd-MM");
  if (startDate === undefined && endDate === undefined) {
    url = `http://192.168/{LastYear} lt ${ThisYear}`;
  } else {
    // if (startDate > endDate) {
    //   alert("Start date can't be greater than the end date!");
    // } else {
  if (startDate !== undefined && endDate !== undefined) {
    url = `http://192.168/$filter={startDate}{endDate}`;
    console.log(url) 
    }
  }


  
  console.log(url)

  return {
    url,
  };
};
export default useURLSwitcher;
```

Answer (score 0):

In general a component will re-render if its state or incoming props changes. The App.js is also a component.

At first glance, when you change a date in `DatePickerWithButton`, it does not seems updating any state/props that the parent App.js is aware of, hence no re-rendering.

The `useURLSwitcher()` just returns an object with url string.

The `onClick` function below only updates the `DatePickerWithButton`'s local states.

```
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState();
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState();

    const {url} = useURLSwitcher(startDate, endDate) 
    

    const onClick = () => {
        setStartDate(tempStartDate);
        setEndDate(tempEndDate);
    }
```

The `GraphChart` component is a child component of App.js, but no state/props changes in App.js, hence, `GraphChart` does not re-render when only the `DatePickerWithButton`'s local states changes.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I'll try to fix it with your feedback. Do you have any suggestions how to optimally tackle this though? I don't want `app.js` to do more than just rendering, but it seems I have no choice but keep a state of some sort for the graphs to re-render.

Comment: You're right, App.js should not be doing everything. One option is to have a wrapper/container component. E.g: ChartContainer which has local date and data states which will re-render Graph, DatePicker, or DatePickerWithButton ..etc when the state changes. Another option is to use Redux to manage state in your entire application.